# Calendar Template in SharePoint 2013 not displaying add link on mouse hover

Tags: list, 2013, calendar, template

I created a list template from calender type. When I deploy the solution, and view that list I cannot see the `add` link when I put the mouse pointer over any date box.

But when I created the same list from SharePoint 2013 calendar list, I am able to see this link.

The following picture is of the list which is created from SharePoint:

[image]

The same thing is not visible from Calendar template list.

What should I do?

Comment: The Calendar from your custom solution is inside a Site Definition, is a template? Is there any code involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been reviewing my site definition and I have a Calendar that is deployed in a Publishing site.
The `Elements.xml` of that list is as follows

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <ListInstance Title="Calendar" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" TemplateType="106" FeatureId="00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106" Url="Lists/Calendar" Description="Community Calendar"></ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

Notice the `TemplateType`. Must be = 106

Comment: Thanks sir, I was assigning `TemplateType` the value greater than 10000. Now I got the perfect output..

Comment: where we can find this Elements.xml?
can you please share the path of that file or location of that file.

Comment: This is set in Visual Studio when you add an object of type List Definition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Really **TemplateType = 106** is important to get the proper functionality of the SharePoint.

```
<ListInstance Title="TestCalendar" OnQuickLaunch="FALSE" TemplateType="106" FeatureId="00bfea61-ec65-4803-972d-ebe775780746" Url="Lists/Calendar" Description="Test Calendar"><
/ListInstance>
```

Please look this `element.xml` file in the VS Solution.